# Затирается указатель this после вызова lua_pcall с кастомным обработчиком ошибок

Tags: c++, visual-c++, luajit

Есть класс-обертка для Lua API:

```cpp
class Lua
{
public /* lua api */:
    //....
private /* members */:
    lua_State* lua;
    //....
};
```

Мне потребовалось расширить информацию о ошибках в скриптах: добавить StackTrace и значения переменных на момент ошибки.

Ок, добавляю функцию вида

```cpp
static int add_stack_trace(lua_State* lua)
{
    std::ostringstream msg;
    lua_Debug record;
    
    msg << std::endl
        << lua_tostring(lua, -1) // original error message
        << std::endl;
    
    for (int level = 0; lua_getstack(lua, level, &record); level++)
    {
        lua_getinfo(lua, "Snlu", record);
        msg << " [" << record.what << "]"
            << " line" << std::setw(6) << record.currentline << " : " << record.short_src // error position
            << " it function '" << (record.name ? record.name : "{no name}") << "'"       // function name
            << " lines " << record.linedefined << " .. " << record.lastlinedefined        // function lines
            << std::endl;
    }
    
    auto result = msg.str();
    lua_pushlstring(lua, result.c_str(), result.size());
    return 1;
}
```

Делаю обертку для `lua_pcall`:

```cpp
int Lua::pcall(int numArgs, int numResults)
{
    lua_pushcfunction(lua, &Lua::add_stack_trace);
    lua_insert(lua, 1);
    auto code = ::lua_pcall(lua, numArgs, numResults, 1); // use add_stack_trace as error handler
    lua_remove(lua, 1);

    return code;
}
```

**И тут началось "веселье":**

При использовании кастомного обработчика и наличии ошибки в скрипте приложение стало падать с ошибкой доступа к памяти.

Минимальный код обработчика, на котором воспроизводится ошибка:

```cpp
int handler(lua_State* lua)
{
    lua_Debug record{};
    for (int level = 0; lua_getstack(lua, level, &record); level++)
    {
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Судя по отладчику во время вызова `lua_pcall + handler` каким то образом затирается значение `this`(сам адрес)

---

**Собственно вопрос:** Почему так происходит и как это побороть?

---

**Дополнительная информация:**

- Проблема воспроизводится только в `Release`
- Сборка для `x64`
- Используется компилятор от `Visual Studio 2017` и `LuaJIT-2.0.x`.

Comment: Эм... Как он может затираться если он передается через регистр?

Comment: @こきん `this` сохранялся на стек при вызове. Оказалось что стек затирался изза разного размера структуры `lua_Debug`. Подробности в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что при компиляции `LuaJIT` использовались измененные заголовочные файлы, а к проекту подключались файлы без изменений(забыли скопировать).

Суть изменений: расширить поле `lua_Debug::short_src[]`(фиксированный массив `char`).

Для сравнения:

```c
// структура при компиляции ПО
struct lua_Debug
{
    // прочие поля
    char short_src[60]; // <<<<
    // прочие поля
    int c_i;
}
```

```c
// структура при компиляции LuaJIT как библиотеки
struct lua_Debug
{
    // прочие поля
    char short_src[600]; // <<<<
    // прочие поля
    int c_i;
}
```

То есть на стеке под структуру `lua_Debug` выделялось меньше памяти, чем нужно библиотеке, так как в программе использовались необноовленные заголовочные файлы.

Как следствие `lua_getstack` пишет данные в `lua_Debug::c_i` по смещению, заданному при компиляции библиотеки и затирает данные на стеке.